# Calling a Button's OnClickListener multiple times

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, button

I'm using two `buttons` with the same `id` in two different `layouts` in my app where when the first one is clicked, the app loads the 2nd `layout` and when the `button` with the same `id` in the 2nd `layout` gets clicked, it loads the first `layout` file. However, my issue is that **this toggling happens only once and after that the button doesn't do anything**. Do you have any idea on how i can call these **onClickListeners** whenever each `button` is clicked until the user leaves that *activity*?

CardViewActivity.java:

```
public class CardViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView cardArtImageView;
private TextView leaderSkillDescText;
private TextView superAttackTitleText;
private TextView superAttackDescText;
private TextView passiveSkillTitleText;
private TextView passiveSkillDescText;
private TextView hpText;
private TextView attText;
private TextView defText;
private TextView costText;
private Button arrowButton;

private int selectedItemPosition;
private boolean isBtnClicked = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cardview_refined);

    // Retrieving the data sent over from MainActivity
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    if (bundle != null) {
        selectedItemPosition = bundle.getInt("Card Index");
    }
    //Toast.makeText(this, "WIDTH: " + SCREEN_WIDTH, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // Initializing our views
    cardArtImageView = findViewById(R.id.cardArtImageView);
    viewDefinitions(false);
    setSelectedViewsInit();

    initCardViewData(selectedItemPosition);

    arrowButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            isBtnClicked = !isBtnClicked;
            if (isBtnClicked) {
                setContentView(R.layout.cardview_expand_details);
                viewDefinitions(true);
                initCardViewData(selectedItemPosition);
                setSelectedViewsInit();
                Log.d("BTN", "Btn Clicked 1st time");
                arrowButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        setContentView(R.layout.cardview_refined);
                        cardArtImageView = findViewById(R.id.cardArtImageView);
                        viewDefinitions(false);
                        initCardViewData(selectedItemPosition);
                        setSelectedViewsInit();
                        isBtnClicked = !isBtnClicked;
                        Log.d("BTN", "Btn Clicked 2nd time");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Sets the required textViews as selected to allow automatic scrolling
 */
private void setSelectedViewsInit() {
    leaderSkillDescText.setSelected(true);
    superAttackTitleText.setSelected(true);
    superAttackDescText.setSelected(true);
    if (passiveSkillTitleText != null && passiveSkillDescText != null) {
        passiveSkillTitleText.setSelected(true);
        passiveSkillDescText.setSelected(true);
    }
}

/**
 * Adds the views's definitions
 *
 * @param initPassiveInfo used to decide whether or not the passiveSkillDesc & ..Title != null
 *                        so that they can be defined
 */
private void viewDefinitions(boolean initPassiveInfo) {
    leaderSkillDescText = findViewById(R.id.leaderSkillDesc);
    superAttackTitleText = findViewById(R.id.superAttackTitle);
    superAttackDescText = findViewById(R.id.superAttackDesc);
    if (initPassiveInfo) {
        passiveSkillTitleText = findViewById(R.id.passiveSkillTitle);
        passiveSkillDescText = findViewById(R.id.passiveSkillDesc);
    } else {
        Log.d("Definitions", "Passive info == null");
    }
    hpText = findViewById(R.id.HP);
    attText = findViewById(R.id.ATT);
    defText = findViewById(R.id.DEF);
    costText = findViewById(R.id.COST);
    arrowButton = findViewById(R.id.arrowButton);
}

/**
 * Initialize the cardViewActivity's views with the data from the CardInfoDatabase.java class
 *
 * @param selectedItemPosition Used to initialize this activity's views if the intent was called from the MainScreen Fragment
 */
private void initCardViewData(int selectedItemPosition) {
    if (cardArtImageView != null) {
        cardArtImageView.setImageResource(CardInfoDatabase.cardArts[selectedItemPosition]);
    }
    leaderSkillDescText.setText(CardInfoDatabase.leaderSkills[selectedItemPosition]);
    superAttackTitleText.setText(CardInfoDatabase.superAttacksName[selectedItemPosition]);
    superAttackDescText.setText(CardInfoDatabase.superAttacksDesc[selectedItemPosition]);
    if (passiveSkillTitleText != null && passiveSkillDescText != null) {
        passiveSkillTitleText.setText(CardInfoDatabase.passiveSkillsName[selectedItemPosition]);
        passiveSkillDescText.setText(CardInfoDatabase.passiveSkillsDesc[selectedItemPosition]);
    }
    hpText.setText(CardInfoDatabase.hp[selectedItemPosition].toString());
    attText.setText(CardInfoDatabase.att[selectedItemPosition].toString());
    defText.setText(CardInfoDatabase.def[selectedItemPosition].toString());
    costText.setText(CardInfoDatabase.cost[selectedItemPosition].toString());
}
}
```

Comment: Once the layouts are swapped back, you never re-set the click listener for the first button (the click listener for the first button no longer exists after the view disappears during the first toggle).

Comment: @pushasha how do i reset it without writting another onClickListener block?

Comment: you can use
arrowButton.performClick();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid this issue, you need to make sure that the `OnClickListener` you assign to the button *always sets the `OnClickListener` for the button in the "new" layout*.

I haven't tested this, but it seems like it should work in theory. Try defining the listener as a private member of your class, then setting it in your `onCreate`, like `arrowButton.setOnClickListener(arrowClickListener);`:

```
private void arrowClickListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // clicked buttton -- pick layout based on button "state"
        int resId = isBtnClicked ? R.layout.cardview_expand_details : R.layout.cardview_refined;

        // set the contentview with the layout we determined earlier
        setContentView(resId);

        // If we're in the "normal" view, find the card art view and set our field to it
        if (!isBtnClicked){
            cardArtImageView = findViewById(R.id.cardArtImageView);
        }

        // do other initialization stuff
        viewDefinitions(isBtnClicked);
        initCardViewData(selectedItemPosition);
        setSelectedViewsInit();

        // set our new arrow button click listener to this listener
        arrowButton.setOnClickListener(arrowClickListener);

        // toggle button flag
        isBtnClicked = !isBtnClicked;
    }
}
```

Sorry if I got some of the logic wrong -- the key in this case is to set the click listener "recursively", in a manner of speaking, which ensures that a listener gets set after every click.

Comment: thank you, this solved my problem(had to do some corrections/submitted an edit). I should have thought about doing this recursively :( . I didn't know i could have a Listener as a member variable, thanks for that info ;) . Best answer